# Value not setting to variable in For Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

When I executed the following loop, the value in %%a is not set to Result1 properly. What should I Do to correct this?

```
for /r %%i in (*.dll) do (

    echo %%i
    set Result1=        
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('corflags "%%i" ^| findstr "PE32"') do set Result1=%%a
    echo %Result1%  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way batch interprets script. You should enable and use **Delayed Expansion**:

- http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php
- http://batcheero.blogspot.ch/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html